# Plotting in objects vs values in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, graph-visualization

[image]

So I have the data from the graph above. (The dataframe is called df_25) I am trying to figure out how to plot this using  matplotlib (or 
 any other function) but can't seem to get the result.

My objective is to make a graph that compares/maps the column 'value' for each hydrobasin

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = df_25["Value"]
y = df_25['Hydro Basin']

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

No matter what I do I cant get the result. With the above code I get  : could not convert string to float: 'Minho and Lima' however I don't know if it is the correct code for the results I want.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: If you need working answers, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what type of graph are you looking for? Bargraph? Linegraph?

Comment: Line graph would be best. Or scatter

Comment: The first point of the graph you're trying to draw would be located at (x, y) = (-, NaN). The last point would be at (x, y) = ("154,00", "Ebro"). I'm not sure where on a set of cartesian axes those would go. I think you need to revisit the core concepts of this dataset. For instance, what does "154,00" even mean?

Comment: To answer one of my own questions, I suppose "154,00" could be European number formatting.